# Capybara/Rspec - Is there a way to test if an input box has been filled before clicking on submit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am learning RSpec and Capybara and trying to test if a user can navigate to the login page (powered by Devise) and successfully login. The test is not seeing the page it should be after logging in successfully. When using the browser, if input is not present, it returns to the login page. I am using Rails 5.

**login_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.feature "Logging in a User" do
    scenario "Logging in user shows special content" do
        visit "/"
        click_link "Sign In"    

        page.should have_content("Password")

        #fill in login information
        page.fill_in 'Email', with: 'admin@example.com'
        page.fill_in 'Password', with: 'some_password'
        click_on 'Log in'

        page.should have_no_content("Wait for the text which is available in the sign in page but not on next page")
        page.should have_content('User:')
        expect(page.current_path).to eq(root_path)
    end
end
```

**Capybara error message:**

```
  1) Logging in a User Logging in user shows special content
     Failure/Error: page.should have_content('User:')
       expected to find text "User:" in "Log in\nEmail\nPassword\nRemember me\nSign up Forgot your password?"
     # ./spec/features/login_spec.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can check if a field has been filled in with the `have_field` matcher

```
expect(page).to have_field('Email', with: 'admin@example.com')
```

will verify the page has a field with a label of 'Email' and a filled in value of 'admin@example.com'.

It's not the cause of your current issue, but is there a reason you're mixing RSpecs `should` and `expect` syntaxes? You really should stick to one, preferably `expect for new code - so

```
expect(page).to have_content("Password")
expect(page).not_to have_content("Wait for the text which is ...
```

instead of

```
page.should have_content("Password")
page.should have_no_content("Wait for the text which is ...
```

Also - you should almost never use plain RSpec matchers (`eq`, etc) with anything Capybara related, instead you should use the Capybara provided matchers

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(root_path)
```

instead of `expect(current_path)...`

Comment: your expecation line was able to verify it's getting filled. I appreciate the additional tips as well.

Comment: @jeepers_brian If this answered your question, please accept the answer (check mark) so the question gets marked as answered.  Btw - I'm guessing your test is failing because you're not actually creating a User with those credentials in the test (unless it's in code you left out)